# Can't compile with pdflatex when I include pgfplots, error on pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex (Missing \endcsname inserted.)

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex

I have a big document with a few inputs, so I can't show everything, but I'm getting this weird error. Without pgfplots everything goes smoothly, no warnings.

```
\usepackage{usenix}
\usepackage{endnotes,epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url,color,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

As soon as I append

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

I get this:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty) (./pgfplots.sty
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.794 ...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}
```

Is my package broken? I'm using Debian, how can I reinstall it? I've never had this issue with pgfplots before.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig,endnotes}

\usepackage{endnotes,epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url,color,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\date{}

\title{\Large \bf Title}

\author{
\small ..
}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{bleh}
Something.
\end{document}
```

Ran $pdflatex mwe.tex and got the same error.

Comment: Please show us a minimal working example (MWE), meaning something compilable with documentclass and the document environment.

Comment: Added a MWE that also breaks.

Comment: Make pgfplots the first package you load and it works. I didn't investigate further (which package clashes), because there are too many for a MWE.

Comment: Still didn't work for me. Got a conflict with multicol. Then algorithm2e.. maybe it's the usenix one?

Comment: Well, I do not have the usenix package (it's not in texlive). So I can't say.

Answer (score 4):

delete

```
\usepackage{program}
```

or move it last, it makes `|` active which will cause issues with any other code using `|`

Note you should also delete `epsfig` (no document written this century should be using that).